# Firefox: make ctrl+enter submit a form, even if cursor is in a textarea

Tags: firefox, shortcut-keys

How can I make Firefox submit a form by hitting ctrl+enter even if cursor is in a textarea?

There are some work arounds to enable this, if you create web pages with jquery. But this short cut should work on all web pages.

Comment: I think you might have a bogus question here.  I know there are some default functions in most websites, but programmers can use PHP and other languages to add, change or override them in order for a site to function in a particular way.  They really can't be overridden by the browser or there would be no security in the site.  It's like asking for a button for your car that changes every traffic light to green for you.  You might change a few, but you could also cause a wreck using it.

Comment: @Buck questions on this site (AskUbuntu) come from users, not developers. I guess users have the right to ask for usability. This common keyboard short cut would improve usability for me. Are you sure that your statement "... They really can't be overridden by the browser ..." is true? There are a lot of browser plugins which do fancy stuff.

Comment: First, can I get an accurate perspective?  Your question sounds like it comes from a website visitor, but your reference to jquery sounds like it comes from a website developer.  jquery is a "library" which means its functions are predefined and anyone using it allows the same functions on their sites.  However, that may not be true for a PHP or other source library.  If you are a developer, you should know how important it is to control what happens within a text field when your user presses certain key combinations. (continued.)

Comment: "Never say 'Never!'"  Someone might be able to override every possible scheme designed to prevent visitors from cracking their sites using control codes in their text fields, but it would probably not be worth it to the legitimate visitor.  Some Wordpress versions can be cracked by submitting long strings with php code attached to certain text fields.  I'm sure WP fixed it, but I still use plugins that prevent it just the same. Yet, every week I see those strings being submitted to each of my sites.  It's possible that it's the very reason your <CTRL><Enter> might not work on my forms.

Comment: @guettli a) some sites have >1 form. b) there are gazillion ways (and addons) to play around with your own personal shortcuts (in firefox, at least). c) to make these personal shortcuts effective, you'd probably want to tailor them to the websites you frequent on a per-site basis. d) if you are looking for sth more universal, are you familiar with the basic Tab and Shift Tab  keyboard shortcuts for form (and element) navigation?

Comment: have you tried adding a 'accesskey' to submit tag with [greasemonkey](http://ccm.net/faq/2095-personalize-web-pages-with-greasemonkey)?

Comment: @AliRezaMosajjal no, I have not tried greasemonkey. I asked this question wearing my "I am a user - not a developer" glasses.  Users don't know how to write javascript.

Comment: @guettli since Firefox does not have any customization of shortcuts (adding to the existing list), I don't think there's anything you can do w/o using scripting and advance methods.

Answer (score 1):

1. some sites have >1 form.
2. there are gazillion ways (and addons) to play around with your own personal shortcuts (in firefox, at least).
3. to make these personal shortcuts effective, you'd probably want to tailor them to the websites you frequent on a per-site basis.
4. if you are looking for sth more universal, are you familiar with the basic <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>  keyboard shortcuts for form (and element) navigation?

Comment: thank you for your answer. Where is the question to your answer?

Comment: @guettli I tried to make a few points clear with my answer. You might want to address some of these issues and plug them back into your original question.

Comment: @guettli as far as *"make ctrl+enter submit a form, even if cursor is in a textarea"* is concerned I can imagine and could outline a number of ways to achieve that for a given website. However, to make this behaviour "universal" for all or even most websites out there...? good luck...

Answer (score 0):

If you are good at programming install greaseMonkey addon and write a script you wish to do with the webpage.

But `ctrl + enter` is a default shortcut keys to add www and .com in the url.